# Wordpress + Bootstrap 3 Parent link highlighted on submenu click

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a Wordpress theme using Bootstrap 3. When I click on a submenu I would like the parent menu item to be highlighted/active. I've already used nav walker and the menu is working properly.

Here is the site: http://www.carpetdesignsystem.com

I found this for LESS, but is there a way to do the same thing in CSS without using LESS?:

```
.current-post-parent > a {
     .navbar-nav > .active > a;
}

.current-post-parent > a:hover {
     .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could target it using WordPress' built in classes for active parents:

```
.current-menu-parent a:first-child {
    //styles here
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I never thought of that.